# Call a SQL function in Nifi using ExecuteSQL or another processor

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-nifi

I am currently using a function in SQL Server to get the max-value of a certain column. I Need this value to generate a specific number of dummy files to insert flowfiles that are created later on. 
Is there a way of calling this function via a nifi-processor?

By using ExecuteSQL I Always get error like unable to execute SQL select query or the column "ab" was not found, when using `select ab.functionname()` (ab is the loginname of the db)

In SQL Server I can just use select ab.functionname() and get the desired results.

If there is no possible way of calling this function, is there another way to create #flowfiles dummyfiles to reserve this place for them in the DB so that no one else could insert or use this ids (not autoincremt, because it is not possible) while the flowfiles are getting processed?

I tried using $flowfile.count and the Counterprocessor, but this did not solve the Problem. 
It should look like: INSERT INTO table (id,nr) values (max(id)+1,anynumber) for every flowfiles, unfortunately the ExecuteSQL is not able to do this.

Comment: in SQL `select ab.functionname()` `ab` is treated as an alias of your table.

Comment: I figured out how to get the maxid with the nifiprocessor by using SELECT TOP1 id from table order by id desc. I still could not figure out, how to add the right id to the flowfiles and to prevent inserts while processing them.

Answer (score 1):

Think this conversation can help you:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/26170/does-executesql-processor-allow-to-execute-stored.html

Gist:

- You can use ExecuteScript or ExecuteProcess to call appropriate script. For example for ExecuteProcess just call sqlplus command. Choose type of command "sqlplus". In command arguments set something like: user_id/password@dbname @"script_path/someScript.sql". In someScript.sql you put something like:

> execute spname(param)

- You can write your own processor :) Of course it's more difficulty and often unnecessary